# unable to launch kubectl dashboard on Mac

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have deployed minikube on MacOS using the instructions here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

The brew install was ok and the minikube status shows

```
  $ minikube status
  host: Running
  kubelet: Running
  apiserver: Running
  kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.102
```

I am able to interact with the cluster using kubectl

```
$kubectl run hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.10 --port=8080
```

Viewing the pods is also ok

```
$kubectl get pod
 NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
 hello-minikube-856979d68c-glhsx   1/1     Running   0          18m
```

But when i try to launch the kubectl dashboard, i get 503 error

```
$minikube dashboard
Temporary Error: unexpected response code: 503
Temporary Error: unexpected response code: 503
```

The Dashboard service seems to present

```
 $kubectl -n kube-system get svc -o wide
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE     SELECTOR
kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   3h19m   k8s-app=kube-dns
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.109.210.119   <none>        80/TCP                   119m    app=kubernetes-dashboard
```

below is the kubectl version info

```
 $kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.2", GitCommit:"f6278300bebbb750328ac16ee6dd3aa7d3549568", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-05T16:57:42Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.2", GitCommit:"f6278300bebbb750328ac16ee6dd3aa7d3549568", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-05T09:15:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Any pointers on what is missing ?  How to get the dashboard working

Thanks
Praveen

Comment: Where did you find command: `kubectl dashboard`?

Comment: It should be `$ minikube dashboard`

Comment: @FL3SH@shudipta  Yes, you are correct, i am trying minikube dashboard and getting 503 error.

Answer (score 2):

Check `kubectl cluster-info`, you can find more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#discovering-builtin-services)

```
kubectl -n kube-system port-forward svc/kubernetes-dashboard 8080:80
```

Your dashboard should be accessible on `http://localhost:8080`, keep in mind that the dashboard is deprecated so you can check [octant](https://github.com/vmware/octant).

Answer (score 1):

Try `$ minikube dashboard` command. It will open a new tab in your default browser showing the minikube dashbord.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to solve this issue with instructions from GitHub issues
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4352

Basically, with these commands

```
minikube stop
minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.authorization-mode=RBAC
kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:default
minikube dashboard
```